# Responsive Embedded YouTube Video Code is Not Working

Tags: html, css

When my browser window is shrunk the YouTube video in my main div doesn't shrink with the browser. I tried some code I found online that was going to "solve" the problem, but it never turned out well and didn't look good. My biggest problem with it, was that the video never stayed centered as the browser window shrunk.

This is the code from the website:

HTML:

```
<div class="video-container">
     <iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/dFVxGRekRSg" frameborder="0" width="560" height="315"></iframe>
```

CSS:

```
.video-container {
position: relative;
padding-bottom: 56.25%;
padding-top: 30px; height: 0; overflow: hidden;
}

.video-container iframe,
.video-container object,
.video-container embed {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
```

Question: Does anybody know how I can have an embedded YouTube video be responsive while staying centered (both vertically and horizontally) in the div that it's located in?

Here is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/MyersAN/xk700bng/

Comment: use relative positioning

Comment: Firstly, you have given your iframe a fixed width and height in your css and secondly, the code posted above isn;t even in your fiddle example

Comment: correct, because it didn't work for me and so I got rid of the code and tried it myself which was a fail. but if i got rid of the fixed width and height how would I have a "default" size for it in the div?

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/xk700bng/2/

Comment: sort of. is there a way though that you can have it centered within the div so that you can see the background?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/xk700bng/3/

Comment: Centered in which div? `#container_wrapper` ? You could just add some padding to the element http://jsfiddle.net/xk700bng/5/

Comment: yes. but how do you make the video appear bigger or more like normal size before it's shrunk? yes, centered in #container_wrapper!

Answer (score 2):

I tried with this class

```
.videowrapper {
    float: none;
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    padding-top: 25px;
    height: 0;
}
.videowrapper iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

and add `div` element with youtube embedded code

```
<div class="videowrapper">
    <iframe width="560" height="349" src="link" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

It works, also you should follow [this](https://css-tricks.com/NetMag/FluidWidthVideo/Article-FluidWidthVideo.php) tutorial with demo code.